# Create my own 'Refine' function

Tags: simplifying-expressions, rule

I'd like to understand how the `Refine` function works internally.

I tried to create my own `Refine` function to support basic cases, my goal is not to reproduce the whole `Refine` function but to understand how it is built in the kernel.

For example:

```
In[0]:= Refine[Sqrt[x^2], x > 0]
Out[0]:= x
```

A naive attempt is to create the rule:

```
MyRefine[Sqrt[x_ ^ 2], x_ > 0] := x
```

Obvioulsy, it works with the following:

```
In[1]:= MyRefine[Sqrt[a ^ 2], a > 0]
Out[1]:= a
```

But not with:

```
In[2]:= MyRefine[Sqrt[a ^ 2], a > 1]
Out[2]:= MyRefine[Sqrt[a^2], a > 1]
```

How to write a rule which works for any positive value in assumptions (`a > 1` also means `a > 0`)?
For example, I'd like that `MyRefine` function behave as follows:

```
In[3]:= $Assumptions:= z > 1
In[4]:= MyRefine[Sqrt[a ^ 2], a > z]
Out[4]:=a
```

My current output is of course `Out[4]:= MyRefine[Sqrt[a ^ 2], a > z]`

Actually, my question is more general. Another example:

```
In[5]:= Refine[Sqrt[x^2], Element[x, Reals]]
Out[5]:= Abs[x]
```

Naive attempt:

```
MyRefine[Sqrt[x_ ^ 2], Element[x_, Reals]]:= Abs[x]
```

Obvioulsy working with:

```
In[6]:= MyRefine[Sqrt[a^2], Element[a, Reals]]
Out[6]:= Abs[a]
```

But not with the following (whereas Integers is a subset of Reals):

```
In[7]:= MyRefine[Sqrt[a^2], Element[a, Integers]]
Out[7]:= MyRefine[Sqrt[a^2], Element[a, Integers]]
```

I have no idea about the approach to achieve this. Which kind of rules must I write? Is there a known algorithm behind?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your `MyRefine` works as written. What you encounter is that changing the 0 to 1, this new `MyRefine` is not defined, so the input is returned as the output. I think you may have a fundamental misunderstanding of how something like your `MyRefine` functions. I suggest you look into how pattern matching works with regard to defining functions. Your `MyRefine` will require additional checks at a minimum if you are wishing to work with arbitrary values of your z term.

Comment: Perhaps my question was not clear. I want is to create a rule `MyRefine` as below:


    MyRefine[Sqrt[x_ ^ 2], assumption_] := *code here*

 
which returns `x` if `x > 0` in `assumption`



For example, expected results:

 

    MyRefine[Sqrt[a ^ 2], a > 0] := a

    MyRefine[Sqrt[a ^ 2], a > 1] := a (because a > 1 means a > 0)

    MyRefine[Sqrt[a ^ 2], 2 * a - 1 > 1] := a (because 2 * a - 1 > 1 means a > 0)

    $Assumptions := z > 1

    MyRefine[Sqrt[a ^ 2], a > z] := a (because a > z > 1)

 
My question is: how to implement `MyRefine[Sqrt[x_ ^ 2], assumption_]`?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure that your approach will give you much insight into how `Refine` works internally. Perhaps a better starting point is the [internal implementation notes](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/SomeNotesOnInternalImplementation.html#7441) which state:

> When assumptions specify that variables are real, polynomial
> constraints are handled by cylindrical algebraic decomposition, while
> linear constraints are handled by the simplex algorithm or
> Loos–Weispfenning linear quantifier elimination. For strict polynomial
> inequalities, Strzebonski's generic CAD algorithm is used.

Answer (score 1):

Trying to implement your `MyRefine` through pattern matching alone is unlikely to work, as it would require explicitly considering a huge number of corner cases. Indeed, I very much doubt that `Refine` is based on this approach. It must have much more advanced internal "intelligence" similar to `Simplify`. I have no idea how that is implemented, but I am certain that it is far from trivial.

For instance:

```
ClearAll[MyRefine]
MyRefine[expr_, assumptions_] := Simplify[expr, assumptions]

MyRefine[Sqrt[a^2], 2 a - 1 > 1]                  (* Out: a *)
Assuming[z > 1, MyRefine[Sqrt[a^2], a > z]]       (* Out: a *)
```

Comment: According to the docs, `Refine` is one of the transformations used by `Simplify`